# Why transition affect the element when the page is loaded?

Tags: html, css

I'm using transition property but when the page is loaded the element background color doesn't shown immediately as I set it to #90f it takes one second and even if i add a margin to it the element won't fit immediately in its right place it takes also a second, so how can I make the page loads correctly immediately not by taking a time to load ?

note : the code works perfectly on stackoverflow or on any online editor but locally from vs code to any browser it cause that problem

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #90f;
    transition-duration:1s;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div>this is div</div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: Are you using an extension for VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

you should delete this line:

```
transition-duration:1s;
```

Comment: no i want to use transition but after the whole page loads